# Problems with input results

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some problems with input results. I have made a button that calls a function that checks empty input fields, but when I click it, it just falls to the last if statement and shows like it's not empty.

I've already tried making blank space arrays, functions for each input field and a function with all the input variables. None of them worked.

Here is what I'm trying:

```js
function Bt() {
  //Event Listeners
  document.addEventListener("click", Bt);
  chk();
}


function chk(n, e, p) {
  var n = document.getElementById("Nome");
  var e = document.getElementById("Email");
  var p = document.getElementById("Pass");
  var txt = ""
  var B = [10];
  [0] = "" 
  [1] = " " 
  [2] = "  " 
  [3] = "   " 
  [4] = "    " 
  [5] = "     " 
  [6] = "      " 
  [7] = "       " 
  [8] = "        " 
  [9] = "         " 
  [10] = "          "
      if (n.length == null || n.length == B) {
        txt = "Escr

eva algo no nome"
    document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = txt;


  } else txt = "A1";
  document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = txt;

  if (e.length == null || n.length == B) {
    txt = "Escreva algo no email"
    document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = txt;


  } else txt = "A2";
  document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = txt;

  if (p.length == null || n.length == B) {
    txt = "escreva algo na senha"
    document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = txt;

  } else txt = "A3";
  document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = txt;



}
```

Here's what i've tried:

```js
function check(n, e, p) {


  //Var and Gets
  var n = document.getElementById("Nome");
  var e = document.getElementById("Email");
  var p = document.getElementById("Pass");
  var txt = "";

  //code

  if (n, e, p < 1 || n, e, p == "" || n, e, p == null || n, e, p == " ") {
    txt = "Estes campos: Nome, Email e Senha 
    são obrigatórios.
    "
    document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = txt;
  } else txt = "pronto";
  document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = txt;


}
```

Comment: can you show us your code ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example an edit your question accordingly,

Comment: Hi, sorry for not showing the code, i forgot to do so...

Comment: Unfortunately, both of your codes has several syntax errors...

Comment: I'm kinda new at JS coding actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many errors in your code. First of all, `function Bt()` isn't called. To properly use `addEventListener`, it should be outside of any functions. Use it like this:
`document.addEventListener("click", Bt);`

Also, if calling `chk()` is the only code in your `Bt` function, then you can replace `Bt` with `chk` in your click event listener.
`document.addEventListener("click", chk);`

The next problem is your `chk(n, e, p)` function. If you are going to declare variables in your function, you do not need to fill out the `()` part of the function. So instead, it should look like this: `chk() {}` with the code to be executed inside of `{}`.

Your `if ()` has the same repeating problem. The conditions inside of the parentheses are checked incorrectly. Each condition has to be checked separately. So instead of `(n, e, p < 1 || n, e, p == "" || n, e, p == null || n, e, p == " ")`, it should really be:

`(n < 1 && e < 1 && p < 1 || n == "" && e == "" && p == "" || n == null && e == null && p == null || n == " " && e == " " && p == " ")` Note that I replaced the commas with `&&`, the "and" operator. It checks if the each statement is true, and if at least one isn't true, then it moves to the next block of statements inside of the or operators (`||` ).

Those are the errors I found inside of the SECOND code snippet you gave us. There may be more.